# find and replace in a file a newline (\n) if next line does not begin with a specific character (|) in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to find every newline in text file where its next line does not start with "`|`". The following example explains what I want to do:

Text file contents:

```
|data1|data2
Output1
Output2
|ref1|ref2
Output1
Output2
```

after processing, it should look like this:

```
|data1|data2|Output1\nOutput2
|ref1|ref2|Output1\nOutput2
```

I could to do this in notepad++ regular expression by finding `(\r\n)^(?!\|)` and replacing it by `(\\n)`. I want to automate this in python, because the file itself is generated through python.

Example2 for follow-up in below question:

```
|data1|data2|data3
Output1
Output2
Output3
|ref1|ref2|ref3
Output1
Output2
Output3
```

Example2 after processing:

```
|data1|data2|data3|Output1|Output2\nOutput3
|ref1|ref2|ref3|Output1|Output2\nOutput3
```

Comment: *"I want to automate this in python, because the file itself is generated through python."* Use whatever language you're ease with

Comment: you want to append `data3` at the end also?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

Comment: Where the heck does `data3`, `ref3`, and `output3` come from?

Comment: i corrected it; initially i wanted to go with data1,data2,data3, ref1,ref2ref3 then decided that 1,2 is good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring your mystery data: `data3`, `ref3`, and `output3`.

Here is the code generated by regex101:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"[\r\n]+^(?!\|)"

test_str = ("|data1|data2\n"
    "Output1\n"
    "Output2\n"
    "|ref1|ref2\n"
    "Output1\n"
    "Output2")

subst = "\\\\n"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

https://regex101.com/r/SMXo4p/1/

Comment: The OP already has a working pattern. They're asking for the python code.

Comment: @41686d6564 Added code

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, thank you so much, worked! and the link to regex101 is very helpful

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, i updated question to include an additional ask, is it possible to make data looks like output example 2 through regex formula? i already looked through documentations, i couldn't figure it out.